# Can't update Android Studio 4.1.2 to Android Studio 2020.3.1 arctic fox

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

Can't update Android Studio 4.1.2 to Android Studio 2020.3.1 arctic fox

Anyone can help me?

[image: Error window image.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by simply downloading the newest version from the [Android Studio website](https://developer.android.com/studio) and running the full installer rather than trying to use the patch.

You can keep your settings and have it remove the previous version, so the result is the same in the end as if you'd just done the patch upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Steps are as follows..

Step 1: Open Android Studio.

[image]

Step 2: Open Android Studio Settings. `File --> Settings`

[image]

Step 3: In settings. Appearance and `Behavior --> System Settings --> Update`.
Please make sure that the channel is Stable Channel. Click `Check Now`.

[image]

Step 4: Click `Update and Restart`

[image]

Step 5: Click `Update and Restart` again.

[image]

Step 6: Click `Exit` when promoted.

[image]

Step 7: Update starts after downloading.

[image]

[image]

Step 8: A few moments later.

[image]

Step 9: Welcome to Android Studio. Arctic Fox!!

[image]

[image]

Thank You..

Comment: this is also a patch installer, and it should get him the same problem he asked